# What's special about the "name" variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the Chrome Developer Tools window, I typed in:

```
> name = ["a", "b", "c"]
["a", "b", "c"]
```

However, `name` became a string:

```
> typeof name
"string"
> name
"a,b,c"
> name[1]
","
```

This obviously isn't true for other variable names!

```
> foo = ["a", "b", "c"]
["a", "b", "c"]
> typeof foo
"object"
> foo[1]
"b"
```

And `name` is defined as the empty string on page load (and, as far as I can tell, cannot become anything other than a string).

So, what's up with `name`?

Comment: it looks like name already exists prior to assigning it to an array. It's value by default is `""`.  I suspect it's a built-in/prototype that is part of the language proper.  Specifics notwithstanding.

Comment: Another thing I noticed, the variable stays set even if you reload the page, which is not normal behavior.

Comment: well, you can have a function called "name" or an object and it will return `function` or `object` from calling `typeof name`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type `name` you are implicitly referencing `window.name`, which according to MDN:

> Gets/sets the name of the window.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.name

Comment: and therefore converts it to a `string`